# exporting the data to an excel sheet after being filtered on the admin panel?

Tags: django, excel, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

so, after i filter information, is there a way I can export that filtered list as an excel sheet? I would prefer to have a button that you can click in the admin page to just export all the info as an excel sheet that is visible currently in the panel.

If this is too confusing please ask more question, I would be happy to help you help me!

my list filters :

```
    list_filter = ('Class','Age',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this external library.

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Export on excel the filtered view in admin site
[image]